# Swift - Tableview with custom cell with button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with a search bar. When the view is initially loaded, I see there is an add button showing on an empty row. This should only appear when I am showing a result. How can this be hidden? I tried setting the hidden property to true but didn't work.

second part is I want to attach a function to the button so that when pressed it will execute code to add the friend in the row. Here are the screenshots I have to support my question:

[image: initial view where button should not show]

[image: after searching where I want to attach a function to the button]

Here is the code for my custom cell:

```
class AddFriendsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.addButton.hidden = true
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and this is where I am populating the cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddFriendsTableViewCell

    if(self.friendUsername != "" && self.friendName != "")
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text = self.friendName
        cell.usernameLabel.text = self.friendUsername
        cell.addButton.hidden = false

    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

awakeFromNib isn't called when you reuse the cell.
Try to add else part in your condition:

```
if(self.friendUsername != "" && self.friendName != "") {
    cell.nameLabel.text = self.friendName
    cell.usernameLabel.text = self.friendUsername
    cell.addButton.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.addButton.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a comment with a format, write comment before downvoting:

try replace:

```
if(self.friendUsername != "" && self.friendName != "")
```

with:

```
if let friendUsername = self.friendUsername, let friendName = self.friendName where !friendUsername.isEmpty && !friendName .isEmpty
```

and as Max wrote, you have to manage the else statement with:

```
else {
    cell.addButton.hidden = true
}
```